# Reflexive $\mathbb{K}[x_1,x_2]$-modules are free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $D$ be a **reflexive** $\mathbb{K}[x_1,x_2]$-module. My question is whether $D$ is a free module?

---

This question is oriented from the **logarithmic vector field** for linear forms.

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $V=\mathbb{K}^{l}.$
Let $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{l}$ be a basis for $V^{*}$ and
$$S= \mathbb{K}\left[x_{1}, \ldots, x_{l}\right].$$

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_m$ be elements in $V^{*}$ and $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_m$ are positive integers.
Let
$${\rm Der}\,S:=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\ell} S \partial_{i}.$$
Then the **logarithmic vector field** $D$ of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_m$ is defined as
$$
D:=\left\{\theta \in \operatorname{Der} S \mid \theta\left(\alpha_i\right) \in S \alpha_i^{k_i} \text{ for all } 1\leq i \leq m\right\}.
$$
The $S$-module $D$ is a reflexive S-module, but not free in general.
In [Takuro Abe's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.05842#:%7E:text=Deletion%20theorem%20and%20combinatorics%20of%20hyperplane%20arrangements,-Takuro%20Abe&text=We%20show%20that%20the%20deletion,only%20on%20the%20intersection%20lattice.), he states without a proof (maybe an easy fact) that

> By the reflexivity, $D$ is a free module when $l = 2$.

In  this  case, $D$ is  a  $\mathbb{K}[x_1,x_2]$-module. I think this  maybe follow from some general result. I  haven't found related references.
I am a beginner at the algebra of hyperplane arrangements. So I wonder whether there exists an easy proof of this result? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Certainly true at least when the module is finitely generated.

Comment: Reflexive implies depth at least two, so by Auslander-Buchsbaum formula, the module is projective and then by Seshadri's theorem it is free.